# Error when starting JBoss Server

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

I'm working on a simple Struts Hibernate integrated application and trying to run it on JBoss server. But when try to start the server I'm getting a error; Please check the error report,

```
INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.0.0.Final "Neo"]
INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_38,Sun Microsystems Inc.
INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build  1.6.0_38-b05)
INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.13-b02,Sun Microsystems Inc.
INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,x86
INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -   XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]

ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=PostEjbJarMetadataDeployer state=Described: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.annotation.Resource.lookup()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Please help.

If any other codes required, please ask, I'll post. Thanks in advance.

N.B:

- IDE: Eclipse Indigo
- Dynamic Web Module : 2.5
- Java : 1.6
- JBoss: 6.0

***Edited:***

Ones after adding this  -Djava.endorsed.dirs="path to my jboss6 home"/lib/endorsed to VM argument in the server configuration page, the error gone off. But still the server doesn't start up.

```
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Any idea my friends? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into this Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=250643

Source : https://developer.jboss.org/thread/160526?tstart=0